# How does setTimeout works on Node.JS, please explain this code snippet

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I was just getting ready to get my hands rough with Nodejs, but while experimenting and playing a bit on the first example, i found some behaviour which I am finding hard to understand.

```
var a = function () {
    console.log('print 3');
    return 5000;
    };

setTimeout( function (){
   console.log('print 2');
   }, a()
);

console.log('print 1');
```

The output to the above code is:

```
print 3
print 1
print 2
```

AND a stupid doubt is, while the above code works, this one doesn't.

```
setTimeout( function (){
   console.log('print 2');
   }, (function () {console.log('print 3'); return 5000;} )
);
console.log('print 1');
```

Please explain the above behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting the code better should help you understand what is happening.

```
var a = function () {
  console.log('print 3');
  return 5000;
};

setTimeout( function (){
  console.log('print 2'); # Executed after 5000 ms.
  },
a());                    # Executed first and returns 5000

console.log('print 1');  #Executed second
```

The following snippet does not work as you never execute the 2nd part of the function.

```
setTimeout( function (){
  console.log('print 2');
  }, (function () {            # Never executed.
    console.log('print 3');
    return 5000;
  } )
);

console.log('print 1');
```

The following will work:

```
setTimeout( function (){
  console.log('print 2');
  }, (function () {            
    console.log('print 3');
    return 5000;
  } )();                      #The brackets () will execute the function.
);

console.log('print 1');
```

**As an aside**

The example has nothing to do with node.js and will produce the exact same results in any browser that responds to console.

Comment: Thanks Gazler for such a beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` takes two arguments (at least, it does the way you are using it).

The first argument is a function to call, and the second argument is the time to delay before calling it.

In your first example, you pass a anonymous function and a Number (the return value of `a()`).

In your second example, you pass two anonymous functions (because you never **call** the second function (there is no `()`)).

```
setTimeout( 
    function (){
        console.log('print 2');
    },
    (function () {console.log('print 3'); return 5000;})()
);
console.log('print 1');
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin for such a beautiful explanation

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the 2nd parameter -- setTimeout expects a number

```
setTimeout( function (){
   console.log('print 2');
   }, (function () {console.log('print 3'); return 5000;} )()
);
console.log('print 1');
```